# Preparing complex username, tenant and password for Passportjs authenticate

Tags: multi-tenant, passport.js

Using **Passportjs** with **Sails** for user authentication on a JSON body (no query/form parameters).

The `userObject` is a bit more complex than just `{ "username": username, "password": password }`. It is a tree and, among other data, contains a tenancy key, to be used on a multitenancy system.

```
{
  "userObj" : {
                "tenant" : id,
                "email" : email,
                "password" : password
}
```

Since Passport only accepts two parameters, username and password, I tried "cheating" on Passport configuration on the custom middleware:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        {
            usernameField: 'customUserData',
            passwordField: 'password'
        },
        function(usernameObject, password, done) {
            var actualUser = usernameObject.email;
            var tenant = usernameObject.tenant;
            ....
        }
  )
);
```

And during the actual authentication call, I rearranged:

`req.body` is JSON

```
req.body.customUserData = {};
req.body.customUserData.email= req.body.userObj.email;
req.body.customUserData.tenant = req.body.userObj.tenant;
req.body.password = req.body.userObj.password;
```

and then the authentication call:

```
passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){ ... });
```

My expectation was that Passport would:

1. parse the JSON payload, grabbing `customUserData`
2. pass `customerData` as first parameter in the function (`usernameObject`)
3. allow me to get tenant and email for further processing

But this doesn't seem to be happening. Before I try debuggin other parts of the code, I need to know if this approach would theoretically work.

Or else, how would you configure and pass username + tenancy to Passport?

Comment: Why do you feel you need passport to accomplish this?

Comment: @RMeeker, not sure what you mean. Do you mean Passport is overkill and I could do with a regular authentication code? What are the situations where Passport would be recommended? What else would you recommend? P. has other strategies that might interest me and I believe using proven OS code is better than writting your solutions. I am trying not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I don't use passport much so that is why I was asking why you think it necessary. I have the same tenet app design and the login if fairly straight forward. Check out this gist with an auth controller with a login / logout action, and a policy to check if they are logged in https://gist.github.com/randallmeeker/5f809e5fae7ce960c4ce

Comment: Thanks, that is basicly the same situation and implementation I have -- it just runs (or should) inside Passport. From this point of view, it really doesn't make sense. I just wonder if I decide to add OAuth/Facebook/Twitter for login if Passport is going to make things easier. I didn't get to that point yet, but if that's a recommended use case, I would like to start dealing with Passport from the beginning to "get acquainted". Of course, if dealing with Passport causes a lot of extra trouble (like finding a way to pass the tenancy to the strategy), I'll just drop it.

Comment: can your users have mutliple tenets? because another option would be to use a dry passport approach and then have them select their tenet after the fact. I have another app that has email addresses associated with multiple accounts. It uses mozila persona and after the user logs in the system prompts them to select the account they would to use. You would set a policy after the password stuff to check for the "tenet" basically.

Comment: They can have multiple tenancies, but each one have a different endpoint. The tenancy is captured according to the endpoint path (/mytenant). This tells the system which db collection to search (tenants have fully separate dbs). Since the db search occurs inside of Passport, I needed to pass this value. I'll probably restrict the tenancy name to the same email domain (to avoid user@gmail.com registering the "amazon" tenant, for ex.) -- this could be used to get the info inside Passport by parsing the email address (username). Interesting, thanks for making me think.